# SQL Charindex vs LIKE operator

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, charindex

Can someone please explain me this weird behavior of the charindex function in SQL? We are searching the values where the second letter is an 'o'. I don't understand why query 1 and 3 don't return 'OO software ontwerp', while using the like operator in query 4 it does show up. Even when I'm searching the capitalized letter 'O' in query 5 the value 'OO software ontwerp' doesn't show.

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (Titel VARCHAR(255))
INSERT INTO @T VALUES
('Mobotu'),('OO software ontwerp'),('Compleet handboek Access 97'),('Compleet handboek Access 2000'),('Compleet handboek Access 95')
```

Query 1

```
SELECT titel FROM @T WHERE CHARINDEX('o', titel, 1) = 2 

  titel
-----------------------------
1 Mobotu
2 Compleet handboek Access 97
3 Compleet handboek Access 2000
4 Compleet handboek Access 95
```

Query 2

```
SELECT titel FROM @T WHERE CHARINDEX('o', titel, 1) = 1

  titel
-----------------------------
1 OO software ontwerp
```

Query 3

```
SELECT titel FROM @T WHERE CHARINDEX('o', LOWER(titel), 1) = 2

  titel
-----------------------------
1 Mobotu
2 Compleet handboek Access 97
3 Compleet handboek Access 2000
4 Compleet handboek Access 95
```

Query 4

```
SELECT titel FROM @T WHERE titel LIKE '_o%'

  titel
-----------------------------
1 Mobotu
2 OO software ontwerp
3 Compleet handboek Access 97
4 Compleet handboek Access 2000
5 Compleet handboek Access 95
```

Query 5

```
SELECT titel FROM @T WHERE CHARINDEX('O', titel, 1) = 2

  titel
-----------------------------
1 Mobotu
2 Compleet handboek Access 97
3 Compleet handboek Access 2000
4 Compleet handboek Access 95
```

Comment: I found it, charindex returns the first position of the searched letter. I had to set WHERE CHARINDEX('o', titel, 2) = 2. My mistake.

Answer (score 2):

`charindex()` finds the first occurrence, `like` matches a pattern, [**`patindex()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188395.aspx) also matches a pattern, but still returns the first occurrence. You could use `patindex('_o%',titel)=1`

```
select titel 
from @t 
where patindex('_o%', titel) = 1
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/JCHFQT86136

returns

```
+-------------------------------+
|             titel             |
+-------------------------------+
| Mobotu                        |
| OO software ontwerp           |
| Compleet handboek Access 97   |
| Compleet handboek Access 2000 |
| Compleet handboek Access 95   |
+-------------------------------+
```

and

```
select titel 
from @t 
where patindex('%e%', titel) = 6
```

returns:

```
+-------------------------------+
|             titel             |
+-------------------------------+
| Compleet handboek Access 97   |
| Compleet handboek Access 2000 |
| Compleet handboek Access 95   |
+-------------------------------+
```